# Convert tree structure to prefix notation

Tags: scala

In below code I've created a tree structure to represent an operation

```
((1 + y) / (1 + 2z^2))
```

How can I represent this expression in prefix :

```
( / (1 + y)  (1 + 2z^2))
```

I've written a traverse function which just recursively traverses tree but how to re-arrange the tree ?

```
object ast extends App {

  case class Node(value: String, leftLeaf: Option[Node], rightLeaf: Option[Node])


  val node1 = Node("+", Some(Node("1", None, None)), Some(Node("y", None, None)))
  val node2 = Node("+", Some(Node("1", None, None)), Some(Node("2z ^2", None, None)))
  val node3 = Node("/", Some(node1), Some(node2))

  def traverse(parent: Node): Unit = {
    parent match {

      case Node(s: String, Some(l: Node), Some(r: Node)) => {
        println(s + " , l : "+l.leftLeaf.getOrElse("")+ " , r : "+l.rightLeaf.getOrElse(""));
        traverse(l)
        traverse(r)
      }
      case Node(s: String, None, None) => {
        println("s is " + s);
      } 

    }
  }

  traverse(node3)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simpler if you to restructure the `Node` class into a `Tree` and a `Leaf`
This is common for recursive data structures.

In scala, you don't need to use `;` and can omit many brackets.

```
 object Ast {

   sealed trait Node
   case class Leaf(op: String, left: String, right: String) extends Node
   case class Tree(op: String, left: Node, right: Node) extends Node

   def traverse(node: Node): String = node match {
     //use string contexts to produce a string
     case Leaf(op, l, r) => s"($l $op $r)"
     case Tree(op, l, r) => s"($op ${traverse(l)} ${traverse(r)})"
   }

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val node1 = Leaf("+", "1", "y")
     val node2 = Leaf("+", "1", "2z ^2")
     val node3 = Tree("/", node1, node2)

     val result = traverse(node3)

     // prints out "(/ (1 + y) (1 + 2z ^2))"
     println(result)
   }
 }
```

Unfortunately, this solution isn't tail recursive